# MVC Foolproof library with Kendo Validation

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, kendo-ui

Is it possible to use MVC Foolproof library with Kendo Validation? 
I have used foolproof before with jquery unobtrusive validation, now I am trying to implement it using Kendo Validation and it doesn't seem to work.

Is there any other library that provides similar functionality and also works with Kendo?

Thank you!